# How do I align the barcode in my esc/pos thermal printer

Tags: android, thermal-printer

The printer doesn't take the alignment into account. The barcode is always printed to the left. Please help.

```
public void printBarCode() {
    byte [] alignment = alignCenter();

    this.mPrinterModule.sendData(new byte[]{(byte) 29, (byte) 107, (byte) 67, (byte) 13, (byte) 49, (byte) 50, (byte) 51, (byte) 52, (byte) 53, (byte) 54, (byte) 55, (byte) 56, (byte) 57, (byte) 48, (byte) 49, (byte) 50, (byte) 56});
    this.mPrinterModule.sendData(alignment);
}
```

Comment: You need to set alignment before sending the bar code data. Currently you are setting the alignment after the barcode data has been transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help. I am using an Epson library on Android. It has several functions for sending commands, sending strings, sending bitmaps, etc. The code below shows how, using this library, you align the content you send to the printer. In this example, the restaurant address will be centered. And everything else sent thereafter.
There selectAlignment function sets the printer into the particular alignment modes. So possibly set the alignment before you sendData?

```
POSobject.selectAlignment(ALIGNMENT.LEFT);
POSobject.sendCommand("ESC d 5");
POSobject.selectAlignment(ALIGNMENT.CENTER);
POSObject.printString("Restaurant Address", FONT.FONT_A, true, false, true, true);
```

Hope this helps.